# How to stop infinite loop when setting initial state from API with useReducer (React Hooks)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-context, use-reducer

I am trying to set my initial state via useReducer. This data comes from an API, so I have placed it within `useEffect` and applied a dispatch method. (I need to use `useReducer` because I have more complex logic to come later.)This works however it causes an infinite number of calls to the API and if I console log the state, it just loops draining the memory.

For reference, when I log with eg:

```js
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(CanvasContext);
// console.log(state);
```

I would just like it to run once on load, however when I add specific values to the `useEffect` array it doesn't help. Is there a way to stop the infinite loop? I have tried to use a check if mounted approach (as recommended by other answers, but don't really understand what I should be doing with it).

Thank you.

```js
export const CanvasContext = React.createContext([]);

function cartReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INITIALIZE":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const initialState = {
  initialized: false,
  robots: [],
  cart: [],
};

export const CanvasProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => {
    getStoredCanvas().then((response) => {
      dispatch({
        type: "INITIALIZE",
        payload: {
          ...initialState,
          robots: response?.data.elements,
          initialized: true,
        },
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {state.robots.length && (
        <CanvasContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
          {children}
        </CanvasContext.Provider>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
// getStoredCanvas
export async function getStoredCanvas() {
  let canvas;
  try {
    if (useLocal) {
      canvas = axios.get(endPoints.local);
    } else {
      canvas = axios.post(endPoints.remote, testLoadCanvas);
      // .then((response) => console.log(response));
    }
    return canvas;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: For starters, you aren't using `await` in your async function for GET/POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're throwing around an `initialized` variable, but never using it. Seems like that variable is only ever relevant whenever the provider is mounted. With that being said, I would move the variable into a state variable and use it to ensure the initialization process only ever happens once:

```
export const CanvasProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, initialState);
  const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(initialized) return 
    getStoredCanvas().then((response) => {
      setInitialized(true)
      dispatch({
        type: "INITIALIZE",
        payload: {
          ...initialState,
          robots: response?.data.elements,
        },
      });
    });
  }, [dispatch, initialized]);

  return (
    <>
      {state.robots.length && (
        <CanvasContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
          {children}
        </CanvasContext.Provider>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```